# How can I find which values I'm missing while debugging?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, debugging, argumentnullexception

I try to add something to my dbcontext asynchronously using the following code:

`var entry = await _context.AddAsync(person);`

However, I get the following exception:

> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: key
>
> at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument argument)
>
> at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.FindEntry(TKey key)
>
> at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryGetValue(TKey key, TValue& value)
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.TryGetEntry(Object entity, IEntityType entityType)
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.NavigationFixer.InitialFixup(InternalEntityEntry entry, ISet`1 handledForeignKeys, Boolean fromQuery)
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.NavigationFixer.StateChanged(InternalEntityEntry entry, EntityState oldState, Boolean fromQuery)
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntryNotifier.StateChanged(InternalEntityEntry entry, EntityState oldState, Boolean fromQuery)
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.FireStateChanged(EntityState oldState)
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.d__18.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityGraphAttacher.d__6.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityEntryGraphIterator.d__1`1.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.d__64.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.d__66`1.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>
> at PersonRepository.d__4.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>
> at PersonController.d__3.MoveNext() in PersonController.cs:line 63

While reading these statements I couldn't find which value(s) I could be missing. And while debugging I don't know what to look for.
How can I find which values I'm missing while debugging?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the ID defined for the person you are trying to add is null. If you don't have a database ID generation configured, then you'll need to supply an ID for the person before you add it to the context.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys for more info on defining a key column for your model (as in a primary key column(s)).